# No gnome-desktop on the LAPTOP screen after connecting a second monitor(hdmi)

Tags: boot, hdmi, python3, .desktop, devices

So two things occurred:

1. I have recently near-nigh killed the system by **deleting python3** (i had too many versions of it installed), but i did manage to reinstall it and the gnome-desktop since then through the CTRL+ALT+F1 terminal and everything worked "fine" for another day or two.
2. Now i connected my ***second screen*** to my DELL laptop(which is th machine in question) and there is ***no desktop on the laptop*** anymore. It just hangs on this boot-sequnce(in the picture). The funny part is i can still use almost everything as normal on the second screen (through the hdmi cable) but this is obviously not ideal.

If i try to access the regular Display settings on the second screen -- there is no "second" option (which is supposed to be the native laptop scren) except my auxillary(connected through hdmi) Samsung Monitor. The laptop's own screen is not detected.

If i try to get terminal with CTRL+ALT+F now on the laptop it throws me into the Ubuntu user-login screen, where once i enter my password it sends me back to the boot sequence.

Another scary thing is that a usb with a fresh ubuntu image is not being detected in BIOS anymore -- that was what i reached for first.

[image]

Please help, i'm totally unsure of how to proceed. I'd really like to get the laptop screen working with the actual system that is installed on it, really couldn't care about the second monitor.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the system log with

```
    dmesg | less
```

to look for anything errors such as the Nvidia drivers failing to load.

Were you able to read the USB after booting your system? If so, then maybe you need to make it bootable with the Gnome Disk Utility GUI or try creating it again.

but my first concern is do you have a way of backing up stuff you want to keep should you have to re-install? (Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Music, code typically).

If you want to build a stable system, consider

```
    sudo apt update
```

and possibly

```
    sudo apt upgrade
```

to get to the next release. My guess is that an upgrade will be smart enough to recognize deficiencies in your system such as missing packages and add them.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you've wrecked your BIOS.

If you cannot recognize the USB stick with a fresh Ubuntu ISO image on it, do you have other USB sticks that may have older bootable distros of any kind, or another USB device of any kind that it can recognize?  If so, then it maybe a media or formatting issue that is to blame.

There are other ways to get to Terminal besides the short-cut key. You can try Activities in the upper left corner and search for Terminal... or other programs you might want to run.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
I can indeed get a terminal actually on both the second monitor the regualr ubuntu way AND on this black one, except with no gnome desktop. But what do i look for? Reinstall what? Any suggestions...? Thanks tons
At this point i have a hunch also that NVIDIA drivers might be involved.

Answer (score 1):

If dmesg shows that the Nvidia drivers tainted the kernel, then removing them could return some stability to your system.

My experience is that fiddling with custom drivers just doesn't pay off unless you have special video hardware because you're a professional photographer for example.  You'll have to do your own homework if that's what you really want.